# How to sort email by date using c#

Tags: c#, sorting, outlook, office-interop, office-automation

I can only sort outlook.item by received time that are sorting only by time and I need to sort them by date.
Does anyone knows how can I sort by date using c#?
Thank you

I've used `MAPIFolder.Items.Sort('[receivedTime]',true)`
And it sorted by time and I need by date

Comment: How is sorting by date different from sorting by time? `ReceivedTime` property includes **both** date **and** time.